# Can I have two structured properties with the same name if they are in different Models?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

According to the Google NDB documentation, Model() kinds are considered a global namespace, so I should not have two ndb Models with the same name, even in different files. Still, Structured Properties are not full-fledged entities, they don't have a key and if I search the console for them, they do not exist, but are properties of other entities. Considering this, can I have something like the following code?

This in file_A.py:

```py
class Specifications(ndb.Model):
    #A list of Specifications

class Car(ndb.Model):
    specs = ndb.StructuredProperty(Specifications)
```

This in file_B.py:

```py
class Specifications(ndb.Model):
    #Another list of Specifications

class Bike(ndb.Model):
    specs = ndb.StructuredProperty(Specifications)
```

Comment: I'd just keep things clear/simple by using `CarSpecs` and `BikeSpecs` instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perfectly do this but notice that is better to have the Specifications Model defined once to not mess around things. But... you can also define two different Specifications models on each file.

Comment: They would have different properties, so it would have to be two different models. So I cannot have two Car models in different files, but I can have two Specifications models because it is a structured property, right?

Comment: Yes, you can. If each "Specifications" Models have different properties you can do it so each is defined with it's own properties in different files. BUT be aware that if you want to import both "Specifications" from another file you will have to alias them.